# Trying to create multi-login library system

Tags: java, user-interface, object, netbeans

I am fairly new to Java, so please bear with me.

So I am trying to design and create a library system, with student & staff interfaces (using NetBeans).
So far, I have managed to create a staff login however, I need to do the same for students. A problem I am facing is that, I need to create these logins, using object serialisation and / or using a .txt file from my local drive. The thing is, I have no idea how to go about writing this, without the use of a database.

This is what I have so far for my staff login:

Methods & Statements for Login Menu

```
    String username = jUsernameTextField.getText();
    String password = jPasswordTextField.getText();

    if(password.contains("student") && (username.contains("admin")))
    {
        jUsernameTextField.setText(null);
        jPasswordTextField.setText(null);
        systemExit();
        this.dispose();

        StaffMenu Info = new StaffMenu();
        Info.setVisible(true);
    }

    else 
    {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Login Details Entered", "Login Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        jUsernameTextField.setText(null);
        jPasswordTextField.setText(null);

    }
```

Probably a long-shot - but is there a way, I can write the login details to file and use the credentials from the .txt file, to login into the system ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you have the credentials for all the users stored in a text file and are trying to validate the input against it? Do you need to pass this information to another system via a text field? Why can't you use a local database (like H2)? It then raises a dozen more questions

Comment: Somewhat unrelated, but instead of `contains` you should relly use `equals` in your if condition.

Comment: How many people, total, do you anticipate you will need to support with login names and passwords?

Comment: @MadProgrammer As part of the assignment, it is meant to be a stand-alone system. I am asking for the best method to store user information, really. Ideally, I'd like to pass the information onto another file, to be re-used later.

Comment: @markspace  I would say at least 3 members in total will need login names and passwords.

Comment: @KADProgramme The "simple" solution might be to use `java.util.Properties` which can be saved and loaded, it's a simple key/value pair, so you can easily associate a user and password together. It's also simple to use (it's just a wrapper around a `HashMap`)

Comment: @MadProgrammer so if I am trying to write a statement that allows one user to create and save details using properties - how should it be written ? So a user would create account for another user in the interface, which would then write the credentials to the script which should allow that person to log-in.

Comment: @KADProgramme [`Properties#store`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store-java.io.Writer-java.lang.String-)